# Having difficult time using or downloading videos with Youtube-dl

Tags: software-installation, youtube-dl

Having difficult time using or downloading videos from Youtube it keeps saying

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl: Permission denied
```

I don't even know if I installed it correctly.
My OS is Ubuntu 15.10 64.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible the executable does not have the correct permissions.

For it to be in `/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`, you probably ran it with a `sudo make install` or similar.  it's in there as `root:root` which is fine, but it's not going to work right.

Let's set the executable bit: `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`

Then try and use `youtube-dl`.

Comment: I think your method works it just started downloading after i enter your instructions. thanx

Comment: @En20 Great!  If this helped you, feel free to click the check mark on my answer to mark this question as resolved, and to mark my answer as the one that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it via `pip3`

At first intall `python3-pip python-pip`

```
 sudo apt-get install python3-pip python-pip
```

then

```
 sudo pip3 install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

Comment: Ok i installed them both, what next/

Comment: not downloading still getting this  bash: /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl: Permission denied

Comment: how do you use that command?  Try this `youtube-dl  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEcmFa-JVWU  --output file.mp4`

Comment: What is the output of  `ls -lhia /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`  ?